# Assistant editor is showing two different version of same file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I'm connecting some `UIControles` to its `IBOutlet` object in .h file using drag and drop.

After connecting i found that those `IBoutlet` Objects are there in .h file, when i'm opening it on right panel of assistant editor.but same objects are not coming when i'm opening it on left panel as given in image [image]

But after some time i found that it has two version of same file as shown in following image
[image]

I filtered the file name in project navigator by its name but its showing only one file of that name

[image]

**What have i tried**:i have cleaned it many times,and i have restarted Xcode many times.

Answer (score 0):

Does it show the file two times on left panel ? Try filtering out by name and see if you have two files there (Project Navigator). Probably you accidentally duplicated this file.

To fix the problem go to Project Settings / Build Phases / Compile Sources and filter out files but that name. Right click on them and show in finder to find out which one is not required.

Comment: on left pannel its showing two file as well,But i filtered it in project navigator by its name its showing one file only

Comment: Delete both of them and re-add a file - make sure to uncheck "copy to target" when you re-add it

Comment: but there is only one file on project navigator, i have updated my question check last screen shot